# What facets should I consider when deciding which guest to jail in ("full") KVM and which in LXC?

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, lxc

Currently I am migrating to a new server. The old one ran 10.04 as host system and a few more 10.04 and Debian 6 as KVM guests. This was alright, because the processor had support for virtualization. Performance was acceptable. Memory was the bottleneck resource for this case.

On the new server I have more RAM, bigger disks, better CPU and I think it wouldn't be a problem to tackle the load (a load that the old one could take without problem). However, I would now like to split the guests into some with a shallow `lxc` based jail and some with the full virtualization under KVM/`libvirt`, providing me more confidence (security-wise) than `chroot`, but bigger performance than `libvirt`/`kvm` at the cost of security drawbacks.

Some of the guests will have their IPs (v4 and v6) "directly" exposed to the Internet (at least or two of the web servers), while others provide services only to the "intranet". There will also be one `nginx` instance which acts as a frontend to several web servers that don't get directly exposed. Should this be the guiding factor, though? The fact whether or not the guests are "web-facing"?

My main concern is security followed by performance.

**The question:** What are the facets to consider when deciding which one goes into an LXC jail and which one becomes a full KVM guest?

Comment: Do you really consider necessary to use any KVM implementation? AFAIK lxc runs on the exactly same HW as the host system so it will be running like if it were a host too.

Comment: However, until about a few weeks ago the separation wasn't as complete as I consider ideal for my requirements.